# cin.clear and eating up input (only using LLVM on Mac?)

Tags: c++, hex, llvm, cin

I'm trying to run the following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str, str2;
    double v;
    cin >> str;
    cin >> v;
    if (!cin) cin.clear();
    cin >> str2;
    cout << str << endl << str2 << endl;
}
```

When I run this on the following inputs, I get the following outputs:

INPUT:
hello 1 world

OUTPUT:
hello
world

INPUT:
hello world

OUTPUT:
hello
world

INPUT:
hello 1world

OUTPUT:
hello
world

INPUT:
hello abcdefworld

OUTPUT:
hello
world

INPUT:
hello abcdefghijklmnop

OUTPUT:
hello
ghijklmnop

INPUT:
hello all

OUTPUT:
hello
ll

INPUT:
hello felines

OUTPUT:
hello
lines

These make sense to me except for the last few. It seems like in attempting to read the double v, all characters between A-F are just eaten up, and I can't get them back. Does this have something to do with reading hex numbers? How do you avoid it?

EDIT TO ADD: I tried running it on a Linux box and it works as expected. On Mac OS X 10.9, using Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) to compile, I get this weird behavior. Can't think what could possibly be happening...

Comment: I'm not experiencing that behavior.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'm on Mac OS X 10.9, using "c++     test2.cpp   -o test2" to compile. Any idea what could be causing the behavior?

Comment: I'm not even experiencing this behavior when replacing `cin >> v` with `cin >> hex >> v` (and including `<iomanip>`). Only when also replacing `double v` with `int v`. I'm on Ubuntu using g++ 4.7. What's your compiler (and version)?

Comment: @leemes I just tried compiling on Ubuntu and it worked fine (expected, non-weird behavior). On my Mac, I'm using Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn). It's also worth noting that even though it eats the A-F characters, v == 0 after the read...

Comment: I now tried *clang version 3.0-6ubuntu3* based on LLVM 3.0 and also no "weird" results. Input: `hello abcdefworld`, output: `hello abcdefworld`. I'm sorry; I don't have another LLVM version. Maybe they introduced some "optimization" which is either buggy or your code is UB (I don't know iostreams enough).

Comment: Thanks. When I get the chance, I'll try it on another Mac. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: looks like a bug with libc++, which is the default c++ standard library for 10.9. If you compile with `--stdlib=libstdc++` you'll not see the aberrant behaviour. It might be good to log a bug

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Should I report the bug somewhere?

Comment: Looks to be already filed - http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17782